# WPF MVVM Multiple View Issue, using ListBox.SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm, viewmodel

I have been dealing with simple MVVM patterns, and have since taken more of a dive into the full capabilities of databinding in WPF.  I have an issue that I ran into that I can't seem to wrap my head around.  Take the following MainWindowViewModel code for starters:

```
ObservableCollection<DataRecord> _SomeData = new ObservableCollection<DataRecord>();
public ObservableCollection<DataRecord> SomeData
{
    get
    {
        return _SomeData;
    }
    set
    {
        _SomeData = value;
    }
}

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    CurrentViewModel.Add(new RandomViewModel(SomeData));
}
```

Instead of pasting the full lengths of code, I have bound a ListBox to an ObservableCollection<> of ViewModelBase, referencing the Image property of each base added (Image Navigation).  Now!  For the problem:

I am using a DataTemplate to reference the View from the ViewModel, using the string returned from the ListBox.SelectedItem.  Because RandomViewModel requires a parameter passed, whenever I click on the ListBox.SelectedItem, a new View is instantiated instead of the one created in the ListBox.  The reason this is happening is simple, the new View requires a RandomViewModel to reference for databinding.  So!  Using the infamous ListBox.SelectedItem for ViewModel/View Navigation, how am I supposed to create the View, and still reference its ViewModel, even though the ViewModel requires a parameter passed? OR!  How am I supposed to use the already instantiated ViewModel and use that as reference to the newly created View?

Comment: I really don't understand what you have.

Comment: I thought the question had enough weight, I guess not!  What are you missing that would help answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

i dont understand why everybody is doing MVVM with view first. i use view first just for the root/mainwindow and maybe a login dialog. for the rest of the application i dont care about the view/xaml at all and take the **Viewmodel first** approach. this is so much easier with mvvm. in your case your mainviewmodel handle the list of randomviewmodel like you did. but now instead of creating a random view and assign the randomviewmodel, you just have to bind the seleced randomviewmodel to a contentpresenter. wpf will look at your resources to find a datatemplate to "how should i render this randomviewmodel" and you see you desired view. of yourse every time a new instance of the view is created, but always the same viewmodel is taken.

and thats what mvvm is for me: dont care of your views just handle your viewmodels right.